# Vector of templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'm having a problem with a little part of code, I'm trying to work with templates and a vector of a template class
A friend helped me with the following code, getting it to a state where it compilles, but I still can't use derived classes well enough, so I'm completely lost and I can't get past this little error, I could really use your help

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>

   class data_base
   {
   public:
         data_base( std::string &_id );

         std::string id;
   };

   template <typename T>
   class data : public data_base
   {
   public:
         data<T>( T &_data, std::string &_id );

         T *data;
   };

   data_base::data_base( std::string &_id )
   {
         id = _id;
   }

   template <typename T>
   data<T>::data( T &_data, std::string &_id )
   {
        data =& _data;
        id = _id;
   }


   int main()
   {
       std::vector< data_base*> stuff;

       return 0;
  }
```

How would one go around using the data class and putting it in stuff vector, and accessing it later?
Oh, and if anyone would know a good tutorial about using base/derived classes, I could really use that
Thanks in advance

Comment: `data_base` seems quite useless, as it has no virtual functions. Are you trying to re-implement `boost::any`?

Comment: I'm using part of this code, in older version in my serialization code, I've recently decided to change it to be template compatible, but I can't get it to work. Is there a way to completely ignore the base/derived class and just skip to one templated class vector in any possible way?

Answer (score 3):

> How would one go around using the data class and putting it in stuff vector, and accessing it later?

It's actually quite simple.  Let's work through some steps.

To create a single instance of your templated data class, you declare it with the type you want it to use in angled brackets:

```
data<int> MyDataObject(0, "zero");
```

You can probably see the similarity with your declaration of `stuff`: `std::vector< data_base*> stuff;` because `vector` is a templated class too.

To declare a vector of types, you place the type inside the angle brackets of vector, as you already know.  So, try this now you know how to declare a version of your class using a specific data type:

```
std::vector<data<int>> MyVector;
```

Do you see the logic?

However, there's a catch: this won't compile on most C++ compilers, but it's not because you made a logical mistake.  It's because the `>>` at the end isn't recognised as part of the type declaration - it's seen as something else (>> has another meaning. I believe this problem in this situation is fixed in the latest C++ specification.)  To fix this, force the compiler to parse it correctly by adding a space:

```
std::vector<data<int> > MyVector;
```

Whitespace doesn't normally matter to a compiler parsing source code, but here it does.

Now you have a vector of your data class using ints.

To read up on using vectors, I recommend [this page as a good reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).  But a quick overview is that you use `push_back()` to append an item to the vector, and can use array indexing, that is `[]`, to access a specific element by index, starting from 0 for the first element, and use `size()` to know how many elements it contains:

```
data<int> MyDataObject(0, "zero");
MyVector.push_back(MyDataObject);

data<int> Test = MyVector[0]; // Gets the first item - since only one was added, it should equal MyDataObject.
```

Note that `MyDataObject` and `MyVector` are both allocated on the stack, so they will be destroyed when they goes out of scope (the method or block where each is declared - a block is a `{...}` section - ends.)  You can also allocate on the heap, and store pointers to your base objects in the vector.  If you want to know how to do that, please comment - I can expand the answer.

> Oh, and if anyone would know a good tutorial about using base/derived classes, I could really use that

Please ask only one question per question.  That helps keep the site organized.  In addition, unlike your first question, I think this is something you can easily research yourself.  But if you have trouble, feel free to ask another question here.

But there is one obvious bug here.  Your code for data (your derived class) has this constructor:

```
template <typename T>
   data<T>::data( T &_data, std::string &_id )
   {
        data =& _data;
        id = _id;
   }
```

See that it initialises the member variable id, which belongs to the data_base class.

What you should do instead is call the ancestor constructor from your child constructor, because it should already do the work of initialising the `id` member. like so:

```
template <typename T>
data<T>::data( T &_data, std::string &_id ) :
     data_base(id) // call parent constructor
{
     data =& _data;
}
```

The items that come after a : in a constructor are the "initialisation list".  In fact, you can put everything there:

```
template <typename T>
data<T>::data( T &_data, std::string &_id ) :
     data_base(id), // call parent constructor
     data(_data)
{ }
```

By the way, try also changing how you name things.  `data` here is both the name of your class, and of a member variable.  That's confusing.  There are a number of different common ways of naming things to make what's what clearer, but the one I personally prefer is to prefix member variables with `m_` (m for member.)  That would lead to:

```
template <typename T>
data<T>::data(T &data, std::string &id) :
     data_base(id), // call parent constructor
     m_data(data)
{ }
```

and change the declaration to match (and change the base class similarly.)  Try to name things so you can distinguish between types, local variables and member variables at the very least.